# Android @ Home framework SDK

Tags: java, android

Google has announced its new framework for Android, its a home automation system API developed for android.

I would like to know, whether they have released the SDK for this framework or not, because my googling didnt help.

Please let me know, about it.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Android@Home is just concept. To develop it, you need to check AOA(Android Open Accessory) API and ADK(Android open accessory Development Kits). There are two type: USB and Bluetooth. Some videos introduce the demo of Android Home Automation using NFC.

- Webpage : http://source.android.com/accessories/protocol.html
- Video : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hYMpMt0lwUY